# jqGrid : setting submitted field name when submitting the edit form as a json

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to submit the form in json format. Everything is ok. json data is generating and being submitted in the server side. I need to catch the submitted data in server side too. And for this i need a field name of the json data. But I found that in jqGrid side its submitting a json but the json object is not associated with any field. How can i set a field against that json data. So that I can try to get the json field in server side.

Comment: json file is not a field in you post request data, it is your entire post request data that is sent in form of json file. BTW what are you using on the server side ?

Comment: I'm using j2ee (Struts 2) in my server end.

Comment: @msngupta : If this is the case then its very hard for the server side code to deal with the json file. Because a file operation is always a costly operation. I think jqGrid must have a solution to overcome this limitation.

Comment: You should post JavaScript code fragment which clear what you do. For example you wrote about submitting the form in JSON format. Do you mean submitting of form from the form editing or you have some form on the page which you want to submit to *load* the grid data? jqGrid don't submit the data in JSON format. jqGrid provide you many way to change format of sending data (during loading or editing) to JSON for example. So it's important to know how you do this exactly. Do you can see correct data sent to the server (in HTTP trace for example)? Is the problem exists only on the server side?

Comment: @Oleg : I agree with you. I managed my current issue by submitting the postdata as request parameter and then at the server end I parsed the request parameter values.